# How can I get pyyaml to correctly display structure in output?

Tags: python, pyyaml

Instead of getting normal line breaks like I'd expect it's just printing '\n'. How can I make the line break actually happen?

```
>>> test2 = [{'A':['a', 'b']}, {'B':'b'}]
>>> yaml.dump(test2)
'- A: [a, b]\n- {B: b}\n'
>>>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `print`? Strings in the interactive prompt like this never show line breaks, you need to `print` it.

Comment: Nope, I'm an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I posted as an answer, mind accepting?

Comment: The interactive prompt automatically displays the representation of the last result — as though you had done a `print(repr(result))`, _not_ a `print(result)` which many think.

Comment: `dump()` expects a second parameter the stream to serialize to, failing to provide that it doesn't know where things should go, builds up that stream in memory and returns the contents. You can of course print that result, but that is inefficient and shows little understanding of how to use `yaml.dump()` as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dump()` routines in PyYAML have several optional arguments, the first of which being the stream the data will be serialized to ( `stream=` ).

If you don't specify this stream a file like object will be created (`StringIO()` or `BytesIO()`) to which the data is serialized and in that case the the `dump()` routine returns that objects `getvalue()`, where it normally just returns `None`.

As you don't specify an output stream, PyYAML doesn't know where to write the output and returns the result of `getvalue()` in your case as string. 
If you would have provided the `encoding=` parameter you would get a bytes array on Python 3 and not a string.

You can of course `print` that string, but that is one of the most common mistakes I see people using PyYAML make. For a small datastructure this is excusable, but for large data structures creating a string representation in memory can consume large amounts of memory unnecessarily.

You should get used to the habit of providing the stream parameter:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> test2 = [{'A':['a', 'b']}, {'B':'b'}]
>>> yaml.dump(test2)
'- A: [a, b]\n- {B: b}\n'
>>> import sys
>>> yaml.dump(test2, stream=sys.stdout)
- A: [a, b]
- {B: b}
>>>
```

This also prevents you from getting a double newline at the end of the output (one from the serialisation, and one from `print`).

Comment: These are going to be generated into fairly significant structures (1000+ lines) so this is a much better answer, thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Fallacy11 I don't completely understand (I'm not a native speaker), do you mean you will have huge datastructures and therefore the memory usage would be significant?

Comment: Yes I'm generating ansible playbooks with various vendors equipment that  have various different requirements. All of these need to be defined in the YAML file, these 1000+ lines will grow significantly over time due to me using different environments and logic needing to be defined (if x environment type use y structure), while performing background monitoring tasks at the same time the larger resource efficiency the better it is for me. If I can feed this directly instead of using print to create a file (which I'm sure I can) will make this much more efficient.

Comment: @Fallacy11 In that case there are two more things to look into then: using the CDumper (as in the first example [here](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)), as that is much quicker. I you want to update the playbooks (read YAML, dump YAML), you might want to look at my package [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) which preserves comments, key order etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the line breaks to render using `print`. Strings displayed in the interactive prompt in this manner never render line breaks. You can tell how your string is displaying by the quotation marks (`'`) displayed around the string, these won't appear with `print`.

```
>>> test2 = [{'A':['a', 'b']}, {'B':'b'}]
>>> yaml.dump(test2)
'- A: [a, b]\n- {B: b}\n'
>>> print(yaml.dump(test2))
- A: [a, b]
- {B: b}

>>>
```